# How to request for more 100 device in wso2iot?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

How to increase the offet and limit more than 100 ? At present we are unable to request more than 100 limit. Can you please help me ???

Answer (score 0):

Pagination works like below;

```
 - offset =   0, limit = 100 ->   0-100 devices 
 - offset = 101, limit = 100 -> 100-200 devices 
 - offset = 201, limit = 100 -> 200-300 devices
 - ....continues....
```

As you can see above limit can be a positive integer(less than 100). Most of the time limit is constant, and we keep increasing the offset for the next API calls.

**For example;**

let offset = 0 limit = 100 when starting; you can do `offset = offset + limit` for the next call.

```
- https://192.168.1.18:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices?offset=0&limit=100
- https://192.168.1.18:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices?offset=101&limit=100
- https://192.168.1.18:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices?offset=201&limit=100
```